# Proper method to POST multiple dynamic elements

Tags: php, html, post, mysqli

I am trying to POST data from a form dynamically allowing the user to delete some rows of the data before submitting. 
[image]

To post the data I am assigning the names to input fields using a similar name along with a variable number as below:

```
 <form method=post>
<input type='hidden' name='mid' value='<? echo $game ?>'>
<table>
<?
$sum = 0;
$n = 1; 
foreach ($results as $result) {
  echo "<tr class='no$n'><td id='no$n'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Delete</button></td><td>$result</td><td><input type='hidden' name='no$n' value='$result'><input type='number' class='add form-control' name='pt$n' value='$pt' onkeyup='total();' onKeyPress='return KeyEvent(event);' required></td></tr>";
  $sum+= $pt;
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<? echo "no$n" ?>").click(function(){
        $("tr").remove(".<? echo "no$n" ?>");
        total();
    });
    });
</script>
<?
  $n++;
  }
?>
<tr><td></td><td>Total:</td><td><div id="sum"><? echo $sum; ?></div></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="addmpanna" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-c">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Which results in input field names as below:

```
<tr class='no1'><td id='no1'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Delete</button></td><td>123</td><td><input type='hidden' name='no1' value='123'><input type='number' class='add form-control' name='pt1' value='45' onkeyup='total();' onKeyPress='return KeyEvent(event);' required></td></tr><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#no1").click(function(){
        $("tr").remove(".no1");
        total();
    });
    });
</script>
<tr class='no2'><td id='no2'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Delete</button></td><td>120</td><td><input type='hidden' name='no2' value='120'><input type='number' class='add form-control' name='pt2' value='45' onkeyup='total();' onKeyPress='return KeyEvent(event);' required></td></tr><script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#no2").click(function(){
        $("tr").remove(".no2");
        total();
    });
    });
</script>
```

I am posting this data and inserting it to the database using the following code:

```
    $addmpanna = spost($db, "addmpanna");
    $mid = spost($db, "mid");
    if(!empty($addmpanna)) {
    $count = count($_POST);
    $count = $count/2;
    for($i = 1;$i < $count;$i++) {
    $no[$i] = spost($db, "no$i");
    $pt[$i] = spost($db, "pt$i");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ank (gid, no, points) VALUES ('$gid', '$no[$i]', '$pt[$i]')";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    } 
}
```

Now, the problem is - whenever I delete one of the field in between the first and last row.
For example: 
If I delete `130`, one of the fields get inserted as a blank and the last field doesn't get inserted as shown in the image below:

[image]

**What is the proper way to POST such kind of data and inserting it into the database?**

**Note**: The name `no$n` is required for deletion of rows, so it can't be removed.

Comment: Using input name like `no[]` will be sent as array for inputs with the same name.

Comment: @frz3993 It is not possible in this case as we are posting multiple numbers.